# dividing columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It's been a while for me to try figure out what is wrong with my code, but I guess I need help. Here is my problem. I have two dataframe which I want to divide each other, but the result was always NaN.

```
In: merged.head()
Out: 
                     15           25          35          45          55  \
Wavelength                                                                 
460         1400.008821   770.372081  585.551187  547.150493  570.912408   
470         1525.470457   807.362906  573.020215  500.984110  489.206952   
480         1848.337785   873.034042  524.651886  410.963453  351.929723   
490         2214.989164   992.325996  566.273806  413.544512  340.781474   
500         2901.445401  1353.389196  807.889110  648.437549  615.930982   

In: white.head()
Out: 
                 White
Wavelength            
460         289.209506
470         366.083846
480         473.510106
490         524.090532
500         553.715322
```

when I try to do division, the result was:

```
In: ref = merged.div(white.White,axis = 0)
In: ref.head()
Out: 
            15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85
Wavelength                                
460        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
470        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
480        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
490        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
500        NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

In this case, what is wrong in my code? 
I also try

```
ref = merged[["15","25","35","45","55","65","75","85"]].div(white.White,axis = 0)
```

with the same result

Comment: does `ref = merged.div(white['White'].values,axis = 0)` work?

Comment: EdChum, yes it works. jezrael has revealed the real problem in his answer, but your suggestion is also works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is in different `dtype` of index and data are not aligned, so get `NaN`s - need same.

```
#sample dtypes, maybe swapped
print (merged.index.dtype)
object
print (white.index.dtype)
int64
```

So solution is convert indexes by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html):

```
merged.index = merged.index.astype(int)
white.index = white.index.astype(int)
```

Or:

```
merged.index = merged.index.astype(str)
white.index = white.index.astype(str)
```

```
#white.index is int, not necessary cast
merged.index = merged.index.astype(int)
ref = merged.div(white.White,axis = 0)
print (ref)
                  15        25        35        45        55
Wavelength                                                  
460         4.840812  2.663716  2.024661  1.891883  1.974044
470         4.166997  2.205404  1.565270  1.368496  1.336325
480         3.903481  1.843750  1.108006  0.867909  0.743236
490         4.226348  1.893425  1.080489  0.789071  0.650234
500         5.239959  2.444197  1.459033  1.171067  1.112360
```